# special extremally disconnected spaces with only finite isolated points

Tags: gn.general-topology, set-theory, measure-theory, ultrafilters

We Know that a cardinal $\kappa$ is ***measurable*** if there is a set $X$ with cardinal $\kappa$ and a {0,1}-measure $\mu: P(X) \rightarrow ${$0,1$} so that for all $x \in X$,  $\mu(x)=0$ and $\mu(X)=1$. also a cardinal which is not measurable, is called ***non measurable***.

Also we Know  this is  ***unprovable*** to find a set with measurable cardinal in "ZFC".

In topology an ***extremally disconnected*** space is a topological space in which all open subsets has open closure.

Also we call a topological space to be a ***P-space*** if all it's $G_{\delta}$- sets are open.

There is a ***well-Known theorem*** that says every extremally disconnected P-space with non measurable cardinal is discrete.

From the aforesaid summaries a question could be posed that:

> Question: If we suppose that a measurable cardinal ***exists***, can we construct an extremally disconnected P-space with only a ***finite number*** of isolated points.

Comment: What do you mean it is unsettled? We know exactly that from the axioms of ZFC it is *unprovable* that a measurable exists. In fact from ZFC and many other large cardinal axioms it is unprovable that a measurable exists. However from assumptions like "There is a Woodin cardinal" or "There is a supercompact cardinal" or "AD holds in $L(\mathbb R)$" we can prove that a measurable exists.

Comment:  @ Asaf, I only assumed that "if" this cardinal exists. In this case it's not important for me to work in which Axiomatic system larger than "ZFC". for unsettled i mean unprovable in "ZFC" to

Comment: (A minor point. I dont see the difference between finding "a cardinal number with measurable cardinal" and finding "a measurable cardinal". According to the definition you give, they're meant to be the same, right? )

Comment: AliReza, the term "unsettled" usually means "an open problem", for example it is unsettled if the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function lie on the line $Re(z)=\frac12$. Unprovable *is* a form of settled. It is an answer. We cannot prove the existence of measurable cardinals, nor we can disprove it.

Comment: @Asaf. you are right. I am not a set Theorist and since i am working in ZFC, i have thought that this problem is an open problem. I do not Know why I have thought that this is an unsettled problem. But there is another Question. you claim that this is unprovable. when we consider this, can we assume  if there is a least measurable cardinal or there is not a measurable cardinal, if we work in "ZFC"?
for notation i will fixe it as soon as possible. 

Comment: Well, you probably know that you cannot prove the consistency of ZFC *from* the axioms of ZFC. The theory "ZFC+There exists a measurable cardinal" is a very strong theory compared to ZFC, in particular it proves the consistency of ZFC (if we assume a measurable exists then we can prove that ZFC is consistent). So assuming a measurable is a stronger assumption than assuming that there are no measurable cardinals. There is a lot of delicacy in those arguments, especially if you are unfamiliar with consistency results. But if there is a measurable, then there is a least measurable cardinal.

Comment: Your title "On the existence of measurable cardinals" is extremally non-descriptive.  I suggest "extremally disconnected spaces without isolated points" instead.  

Comment: Can you please give a reference for the "well-known theorem"?  It might help those who want to learn more about the known background. 

Also, do you know if such spaces can be compact?  If you are looking for compact (0-dim, which is true here) spaces, then we could translate the problem to a problem about Boolean algebra. 

Comment:  Dear Goldstern, I should recall that a P-space is compact if and only if it is finite. so it doesn't make sense in our problem. The reference for the well-Known theorem in my question is: exercise [12 H.6] of chapter 12 in the text "rings of continuous functions".

Comment: If there are only finitely many isolated points, you can remove them and are still left with an extremely disconnected space, right? And still a P-space? But now without isolated points. 

Comment: You probably want your space to be Hausdorff, otherwise there is an example with 2 points. 

Comment: I think the "well-known theorem" is not formulated correctly.  If you add to an extremally disconnected P-space any number of discrete points, the space is still extremally disconnected and a P-space. If the original space was not discrete, the new space won't be either. Perhaps you meant to say that such a space has to have AT LEAST the cardinality of the least measurable. 

Answer (score 8):

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal with $\sigma$-complete ultrafilter $U$.  Let $X$ be the set of all finite sequences from $\kappa$. For $s\in X$, $i\in \kappa$, we write $(s,i)$ for the sequence you get by appending $i$ to $s$, similarly $(s,i,j)$, etc.  We call a subset $A \subseteq X$ closed if it has the following property:

- Whenever $s$ in $X$, and almost all successors of $s$ are in $A$, then also $s$ is in $A$:

More precisely: If the set $\{i \in \kappa: (s,i)\in A\}$is in $U$, then also $s\in A$.

[EDITED:] In other words: A set $O$ is open if for all $s\in O$ also almost all successors of $s$ are in $O$. 
<strike>(Using the countable completeness of $U$, a neighborhood base of $s$ is given by the sets $O_{s,F}:=\{s\}\cup \{(s,i,j,\ldots, k): i,j,\ldots ,k\in F\}$, for $F\in U$. Using the fact that $U$ is non-principal one can show that these sets are clopen.)</strike>(DELETED, see Joseph's comment below.)

We check that $X$ is extremally disconnected: If $O$ is open, and $A$ is the closure of $O$, we claim that $A$ is open.  So let $s\in A$. 
If $s\in O$, then $s$ has a neighborhood in $A$, and we are done.   So assume that $s$ is not in $O$.  Then almost all successors of $s$ must also be  in $A$, otherwise $A\setminus \{s\}$ is closed. So $A$ is open.

The fact that $X$ is a p-space follows from the countable closure of $U$. It is clear that $X$ has no isolated points.

Comment: I don't think the sets $O_{s,F}$ really form a neighborhood basis for $s$. It seems like a way to get around this is to only take increasing sequences from $\kappa$ and assume that the ultrafilter is a normal ultrafilter. Or you can just take another basis.

Comment: You are right.   Thank you. For some stupid reason I thought that there are only countably many finite sequences.  Thinking too much about Laver trees.   


Comment: Whenever $s\in X$, and $\bar A=(A_t:s \le t)$ is a family of sets in $U$, then $\bar A$ naturally defines a clopen neighborhood $O=O_{\bar A}$  of $s$, and these neighborhoods form a base: $s\in O$, all elements of $O$ extend $s$, and for each $t\in O$ we have $(t,i)\in O$ iff $i\in A_t$. 

Comment: This is a really nice topological space which is very much related to Prikry forcing. Let's take a normal ultrafilter $M$ on a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ and define a topology on $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ where a subset $U\subseteq[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ is open if and only if for each $(a_{1},...,a_{n})\in U$ there is some $A\in M$ where if $a\in A,a>a_{n}$, then $(a_{1},...,a_{n},a)\in U$ as well. Then $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ is extremally disconnected, so the Boolean algebra of clopen sets of $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ is a complete and it is the completion of the Prikry forcing.

Comment: Furthermore, the extremal disconnectedness of $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ is equivalent to the Prikry lemma which states that for every statement $\sigma$ and every stem $s$ (the stems are the elements in the space $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$) there is some $A\in M$ where $(s,A)$ decides $\sigma$. I have not seen any papers or investigations where this relation between Prikry forcing and general topology has been seriously investigated before even though it seems very interesting.